# How to check if Bootstrap dropdown is loaded

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

In my case, I need to load Bootstrap-dropdown if it's not already loaded.

I can't check for the existence of the`<script>` tag because all the js libraries are minified and compressed in one file.

I tried to use this method :

```
if (typeof functionName == 'undefined') {
    $.getScript('/BootStrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js');
}
```

but the problem is that the functions names in this library are
( function a, function b etc ) so I can't rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can test for the existence using the following:

```
try {
  $('#my_dropdown').dropdown();
} catch(e) {
  alert('Bootstrap Dropdown init is not a supported action');
}
```

This will run your code as expected but if the dropdown function is not defined by bootstrap, then an alert will be displayed.

Comment: I don't want to test it on a specific selector,
I just need to know if this library has been loaded or not.
So I can only load it when it's not.
I tried checking the existence of this plugin's namespace like this:
if(typeof $.fn.dropdown === 'undefined') {
Load plugin
}
But its not working also.
Any ideas?